# Is UIColor's CGColor accessor a property or method?

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I found a curious bit of code near the bottom of `UIColor.h` (lines 69-71 in my SDK):

```
// Access the underlying CGColor or CIColor.
@property(nonatomic,readonly) CGColorRef CGColor;
- (CGColorRef)CGColor NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED;
```

Why is `CGColor` defined as both a property and a method? Is it truly a property but just defined as a method so they use the two annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method is the synthesized getter method of the property, which needs to be declared to be able to assign the return annotations